# How Do I debug issues on codeigniter web app

Tags: php, codeigniter

Many things have been making my school web application malfunction. One of which is the students' result page. Scores are not been calculated properly, values are not showing up.

For example, the student who has the scores in the image below shows he has both the highest and lowest scores in his class. However, there are others with both higher and lower marks.

[image: miscalculated result]

Everything used to work properly, even now on localhost. I'm on the latest PHP version.

How do I start debugging. What could be the problem?

Comment: You have to start using tests before to use your app in production.

Answer (score 1):

You will need one or two things for it:

[PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/)

[Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/)

The first one is for testing purposes.
The second one is for debugging your code with breakpoints.

Implementation depends on the environment (Windows, Linux, macOS, Docker) in which you are using it and your IDE(PHPStorm, VSCode, Atom, etc)

Comment: This is all new to me but will definitely check them out